# Changes to the DataGrid from v. 3.5sp1 (ToolKit) to .Net 4.0

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I recently discovered that some functionality has been changed drastically in the DataGrid since it made it into the general 4.0 framework (Using BindingGroups for one).

Can anyone point me at a list of changes (breaking or non-breaking)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately at least an official list does not seem to be available (which is a pity indeed), as informally confirmed by Lester Lobos answer to the similar question [Official WPF DataGrid compared to WpfToolkit datagrid](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/4225170b-3951-428c-9966-03c6ae466862) in the [MSDN WPF forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/threads):

> the features should be similar for most scenarios... however, there isnt any documented list

Lester seems to be a [Lead Software Engineer (QA) at Microsoft Corporation](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/lester-lobo/20/82/13b) involved with the WPF team at least, so he should be in the know.

Only slightly related but still good to know in this context is Bob Baos answer to the more general question [WPF Toolkit in WPF 4.0](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sr-Latn-CS/wpf/thread/aca09748-dd76-4700-ac83-1d9a4c559276):

> I get a mesage from a consultation in the internal WPF discussion. Unfortunately, the WPF Toolkit will not be updated to 4.0 anytime soon.

Comment: A pity (or PITA), indeed :-). IMHO, introducing BindingGroups is not 'similar' functionality... Thanks for taking the time to investigate it.

I'll award the bounty when I can.

Comment: @Goblin - agreed, this is a significant change in fact, which should be properly documented at least to help with migration! And you are welcome of course: I do enjoy investigating once in a while for procrastination anyway, your bounty made it more worthwhile even, thanks :)